# How to match text ignoring comma or any other special character

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I want on query "HollandPark" or "Holland Park, Notting Hill" or "holland park notting hill" match this text "Holland Park, Notting Hill". How can I do this in mongodb?

Comment: It depend on which characters you mean by "any other character". Will letters match, like "HollandoPark"?

Comment: @MrLister I mean on ignoring special characters, anything except numbers and letters.

Answer (score 0):

To make this most performant and to cover the most cases, you should really have a normalized field preprocessed with location names. For instance you can have a field holland_park_notting_hill and match that by tokenizing the input as well. But if you are doing this sort of work, you might as well index your data in Elasticsearch and get a lot more powerful matchers.